# Show popup after user in the page more than 15 seconds

Tags: jquery

Did a small logic based on the requirement. Tried my best to meet below issue. But, still Struck with below logic.

If the visitor mouse out of window, show popup (This works fine)

*But, we need to show popup only, when user was in this page more than 15 seconds and mouse out of window.*

**HTML**

```
<div id="demo-fancybox-modal" data-delaytoshow="15">
  <div class="content">
    Demo Content
  </div>
  <button data-fancybox-close="" class="fancybox-close-small" title="Close"><svg class="icon-container"><use href="icons/symbols.svg#i-close" xlink:href="icons/symbols.svg#i-close"></use></svg></button>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var dataDelayToShow = component.attr('data-delaytoshow');
var cookieDelaySecond = dataDelayToShow * 1000;
setTimeout(function () {
  $.fancybox.open(component,{clickSlide: false});
}, cookieDelaySecond);


$(document).mouseleave(function () {
  $.fancybox.open($('#demo-fancybox-modal') ,{clickSlide: false});
});
```

Comment: Sowing popup every page 15 seconds?

Comment: We need to check whether user in this page for 15 seconds or more. More than 15 seconds means, if user mouse out of window... need to show fancybox popup. this is the logic required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a time variable in the page load. Whenever the user do mouse leave event check the time difference and show the popup.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var loadTime = new Date();
  $(document).mouseleave(function () {
    var leaveTime = new Date();
    var diff = leaveTime - loadTime;
    var sec = diff/1000;
    if(sec > 5){
      alert('Leaving after 5 seconds')
    }
    loadTime = new Date();
  });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a timeout for this. You can store the time somewhere on page load. Then when user leaves the window, compare current time with the stored one and and if more than 15 seconds, then open popup, otherwise don't.

Answer (score 0):

try below solution.

```js
var time = 0;
var dataDelayToShow = 15;

$(document).ready(function(){

var cookieDelaySecond = dataDelayToShow * 1000;


setInterval(function () {
   
 time = time + 1;
}, 1000);
})

$(document).mouseleave(function () {
if(time >= dataDelayToShow)
{
  time= 0;
  alert("your code")
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="demo-fancybox-modal" data-delaytoshow="15">
  <div class="content">
    Demo Content
  </div>
  <button data-fancybox-close="" class="fancybox-close-small" title="Close"><svg class="icon-container"><use href="icons/symbols.svg#i-close" xlink:href="icons/symbols.svg#i-close"></use></svg></button>
</div>
```